# bernardphp/bernard: Is there way to check if there are any tasks waiting?

Tags: php

We use Bernard and FlatFile for persistency. I'd like to be able to check if there are any messages in a specific queue. What's the best way to do this? It's both to reduce overhead and also to be able to monitor the whole thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `countMessages` function (on each queue backend's driver) you can use.

https://github.com/bernardphp/bernard/blob/3ff88921bea87186d1baffc93708dd7aee4e963e/src/Driver.php#L28